# How to detect if the mouse is over an object inside the canvas without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a small 2d hockey game where the player selects the puck and shoots it. At the moment my code allows the player to select the puck from anywhere on the page, but ideally I would like to do it so that it's only possible to select the puck If the player clicks on top of it.

Here's the part that at the moment takes control of the puck:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownHandler, false);
// For mousecontrols

// When user clicks, the puck starts following the cursor
function mouseDownHandler(e) {

document.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpHandler, false);
function mousemoveHandler(e) {
var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
var relativeY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
if (relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
  x = relativeX - 18 / 2;
} if (relativeY > 0 && relativeY < canvas.height) {
  y = relativeY - 20 / 2;
}
}
function mouseUpHandler(e) {
dx = -dx + 0;
dy = -dy - 0;
x += 0;
y += 0;
document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveHandler,     false);
}
}
```

Here's also a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrydoukt/).

Thank you very much!

Comment: That was done with Jquery so I wanted to have a new one without it :)

Comment: I can't see any jQuery specific thing in your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

The puck here can be dragged around and "thrown" around the canvas.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
   void function() {
    
    "use strict";
    
    // Variables
    var canvasWidth = 180;
    var canvasHeight = 160;
    var canvas = null;
    var ctx = null;
    var puck = null;
    var lastPuckPosition = {x: 0.0,y: 0.0};
    var isPuckGettingDragged = false;
    
    // Classes
    function Puck(x,y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.dx = 0.0;
     this.dy = 0.0;
    }
    
    Puck.prototype = {
     RADIUS: 10.0,
     MAX_SPEED: 5.0,
     DAMPENING: 0.98,
     EPSILON: 0.1,
     
     // A point is inside a circle if
     // the distance from that point to the circle's center
     // is less than it's radius
     isIntersecting: function(x,y) {
      var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x - x,2.0) + Math.pow(this.y - y,2.0));
      return distance < this.RADIUS;
     },
     
     tick: function() {
      // Bounce off boundaries
      if (this.x < this.RADIUS) {
       this.x = this.RADIUS;
       this.dx = -this.dx;
      }
      
      if (this.x > canvasWidth - this.RADIUS) {
       this.x = canvasWidth - this.RADIUS;
       this.dx = -this.dx;
      }
      
      if (this.y < this.RADIUS) {
       this.y = this.RADIUS;
       this.dy = -this.dy;
      }
      
      if (this.y > canvasHeight - this.RADIUS) {
       this.y = canvasHeight - this.RADIUS;
       this.dy = -this.dy;
      }
      
      // Slow the puck down
      this.dx = this.dx * this.DAMPENING;
      this.dy = this.dy * this.DAMPENING;
      
      if (this.dx > -this.EPSILON && this.dx < this.EPSILON) {
       this.dx = 0.0;
      }
      
      if (this.dy > -this.EPSILON && this.dy < this.EPSILON) {
       this.dy = 0.0;
      }
      
      this.x += this.dx;
      this.y += this.dy;
     },
     
     render: function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "darkred";
      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.RADIUS,0.0,2.0 * Math.PI,false);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
     }
    };
    
    // Functions
    function onMouseDown(e) {
     var bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
     var x = e.clientX - bounds.left;
     var y = e.clientY - bounds.top;
     
     if (puck.isIntersecting(x,y)) {
      isPuckGettingDragged = true;
      
      puck.x = x;
      puck.y = y;
      puck.dx = 0.0;
      puck.dy = 0.0;
      lastPuckPosition.x = x;
      lastPuckPosition.y = y;
     }
    }
    
    function onMouseMove(e) {
     if (isPuckGettingDragged) {
      var bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      var x = e.clientX - bounds.left;
      var y = e.clientY - bounds.top;
      
      lastPuckPosition.x = puck.x;
      lastPuckPosition.y = puck.y;
      puck.x = x;
      puck.y = y;
     }
    }
    
    function onMouseUp(e) {
     if (isPuckGettingDragged) {
      isPuckGettingDragged = false;
      
      puck.dx = puck.x - lastPuckPosition.x;
      puck.dy = puck.y - lastPuckPosition.y;
      
      var magnitude = Math.sqrt(puck.dx * puck.dx + puck.dy * puck.dy);
      
      if (magnitude > puck.MAX_SPEED) {
       var newMagnitude = (1.0 / magnitude) * puck.MAX_SPEED;
       
       puck.dx = puck.dx * newMagnitude;
       puck.dy = puck.dy * newMagnitude;
      }
     }
    }
    
    function loop() {
     // Tick (Update game logic)
     puck.tick();
     
     // Render
     ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
     ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
     
     puck.render();
     //
     requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    
    // Entry Point (Runs when the page loads)
    onload = function() {
     canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     canvas.width = canvasWidth;
     canvas.height = canvasHeight;
     canvas.onmousedown = onMouseDown;
     canvas.onmouseup = onMouseUp;
     canvas.onmousemove = onMouseMove;
     
     ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     puck = new Puck(canvasWidth >> 1,canvasHeight >> 1);
     
     loop();
    }
    
   }();
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```